# what are CI config details for jenkins build job for cypress.io to run in build process, and to record to cypress dashboard?

Tags: cypress

I want to integrate cypress in the jenkins build process and see test results in jenkins build process.  The CI integration details on cypress.io provide starting point for CI with Travis and Circle at https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html with command line options at https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#cypress-run.

For the execute part of the build in jenkins, I could add an "execute shell" to node_modules/.bin/cypress run --record --key xxxxxx

I see how this pass/fail will set build status in jenkins.
I don't see how detailed test results get integrated back into jenkins.
I can view detailed test results in cypres.io dashboard but would rather see in one place in jenkins like I get with sonar.

I'm looking for wiki or details beyond the existing docs on cypress.io to set up CI Jenkins.

And I would like to record the results on cypress.io dashboard with branch, author, commit and message.  Again, cypress.io docs for command line arguments to set those values are not there.

Answer (score 1):

So cypress dashboard is a feature that you would have to pay for if you wanted to keep the results private. Depending on how exactly you want to archive your results (sorry I have never used sonar) you could just run `cypress run` inside Jenkins, and use a reporter to expose the results and do as you wish with them. I personally use mocha awesome and archive after a build, but the possibilities are endless.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/reporters.html#

Comment: I am trying to run cypress tests on the jenkins running on a RHLS VM, it works locally but `cypress run` script simply hangs and does not print the test results. The documentation says something about ~/.cache/Cypress, is this something that you did ? or does the jenkins env. need something for it to run cypress ?

Comment: Did you wait for the server to boot up before running cypress?

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Booting-Your-Server

They recommend an npm module called wait-on.

`
## background your server
npm start &

## poll the server over and over again
## until it's been booted
wait-on http://localhost:8080

## and now run cypress
cypress run
`

Comment: yes, the cypress test scripts are just hanging indefinitely. Do you have any idea why? related: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-documentation/issues/355

Comment: I had issues running cypress on our mac Jenkins machine. If you ssh in and run the test manually does it work? An alternative could also be running the cypress docker image and map a volume on your ci machine to it.

Comment: It does NOT work when I do that. It does the same thing when I ssh into the VM and run the jenkins pipeline: which is to hang indefinitely with nothing being outputted: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1927